# How to Enable BITS Uploads on IIS7

Tags: iis, microsoft-bits

I have installed WindowsServer2008 R2 into a virtual machine with BITS extensions.

I can download files from the webserver so BITS is installed and working, however I do not see a handler mapping for BITS in the Default web site or any virtual directory from which I can download.  There aren't any filters either.  How is IIS resolving this (I can only see the resolution path when tracing failed requests)?

The moment I enable BITS uploads on either the default web site or a virtual directory, I can no longer download files from that directory, and all attempts to upload result in an HTTP 500 error - The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007e).  Also, a handler mapping called 'BtisHandler' is enabled and appears first in the ordered list of handlers.

So In short, how is the BITS handler being resolved for downloads and uploads?  How do I enable BITS Uploads?